# Gitlab Disconnected Fork or Export?

Tags: git, gitlab

I have the following workflow that I cannot figure out how to implement on gitlab.com

I have 2 repositories, Database and Report Cases. The Database repository contains schema object code as well as SQL templates used for generating different CSV reports as requested by our customers. Customers open a case in our ticket system when they want a report. The reporting anaylst team then selects the appropriate template, fills-in the blanks, executes and exports the results then delivers back to the client.

The Database repository is where we store the schema (tables, views,...etc.) object code for our warehouse as well as the reporting templates which are SQL files. The Reporting Cases repository is where we want to store the results of each completed reporting case request.

The Main branch of the Database repository has two top-level folders:

- Database Schema Objects
- Reporting Templates

The Report Cases repository is an automated fork of the Database repository. The fork is refreshed every 5 minutes or so.

The workflow for a case is *supposed to be* the following

1. Case assigned to an analyst
2. Analyst creates a branch in Report Cases from the Main in Report Cases (which again is a fork of Database Schema Objects)
3. Analyst does their work in the new Report Cases branch...
4. Analyst submits a Merge request for their branch for code review
5. Code Reviewer approves but instead of approving the merge they close the case. Closing without a merge prevents case-level code from overwriting the master templates in Main

We are having loads of problems with the above workflow.

Screw up 1. On Step 4, analysts are frequently accidentally creating merge requests from the Report Cases repository fork to the Database repository. So far it hasn't generated any havoc but it obviously could create problems.

Screw up 2. Step 5. Even if the analyst targets the Report Cases fork for the merge, Code reviewers have sometimes accidentally merged after approving. This accidental merge then has to be rolled back.

I have used Git for over a decade on other teams and even I have screwed up both 1 & 2 multiple times. The rest of the team is brand spanking new to any real rational source control system. Until now they have been using a shared cloud drive to handle everything.

We have started layering on automated rollbacks, multiple approver requirements, even merge retargeting to work around the problems but it all feels really rickety and unnatural.

There must be a simpler way to do this than what we are contemplating.

The solution I favor is move the templates into the Reporting Cases repository and break the fork permanently. But I have some colleagues that are adamant that there should be one and only one repository for all code but reporting cases should be in a separate repository. Seems like madness to me but I would love to hear from others.